# Filtering render functions from CodeClimate method-lines check

Tags: reactjs, code-climate

We're adding CodeClimate to a project and running into a lot of `method-lines` errors for the `render` functions in our React components,

example:-

> Function `render` has 78 lines of code (exceeds 40 allowed). Consider refactoring.

We would like to filter out all our `render` functions from the `method-lines` check.  We could increase the line threshold or disable the check altogether, but we still want the check for other functions, so that's not desirable.

There is [node filtering](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate-duplication#node-filtering) for duplication checks, but I can't find anything similar for `method-lines`.

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate-duplication/issues/326

Answer (score 1):

To exclude specific functions from the method-lines check in CodeClimate, you can use the method-lines.ignore configuration option in your .codeclimate.yml file. This option allows you to specify a list of regular expressions that match the names of functions that you want to exclude from the check.

For example, to exclude all render functions in your React components from the method-lines check, you could use the following configuration:

```
method-lines:
  ignore:
    - "render"
```

This will ignore any function with a name that matches the regular expression "render". Note that this will also ignore any function with a name that contains the string "render", such as myRenderFunction.

You can also use more complex regular expressions to match specific function names. For example, to only ignore render functions in a specific module, you could use a regular expression like this:

```
method-lines:
  ignore:
    - "moduleA/render"
```

This will only ignore functions with names like moduleA/render, moduleA/renderFoo, etc.

Answer (score -3):

you need a `codwclimate.yml` file and you can change the threshold with the following - although having a giant render function isn't really great - i'd suggest keeping it under 50 lines as well.

```
version: "2"         # required to adjust maintainability checks
checks:
 argument-count:
   config:
     threshold: 4
   complex-logic:
    config:
     threshold: 4
   file-lines:
    config:
     threshold: 250
   method-complexity:
    config:
     threshold: 5
   method-count:
    config:
     threshold: 20
   method-lines:
    config:
     threshold: 25
```

this is from the docs here: https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/advanced-configuration#section-default-check-configurations

`method-lines` is the last one above - and please make sure to not cut/paste as the YML will need the indentation to be exact.  Good luck!

Comment: How do this config affect only on render functions?  or will it affect all functions?